# Get the value from a java public class with key reference

Tags: java, reference

We have a java public class as,

```
public class Test {
    public class ob1 {
        public static final String test = "T1T1";
        public static final String test2 = "T7T7";
    }

    public class ob2 {
        public static final String test = "T2T2";
        public static final String test2 = "T8T8";
    }

    public static String getVal(int type, String key) {
        return type == 1 ? ob1.key : ob2.key;
    }
}
```

How to get the value from class object like,

```
String t = Test.getVal(1, test);   /// This should return T1T1

String t = Test.getVal(2, test2);  /// This should return T8T8
```

Comment: Where are `ob1.key` and `ob2.key` defined?

Comment: use reflection to get the values

Comment: Something like `Test.getVal(1, test); ` where we should get the value of string test from ob1

Comment: You should either define keys as `public static` members of `ob1` and `ob2`, or have instances of `ob1` and `ob2` in your `Test` object

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the original problem you are trying to solve? Since what you seem to want to do is not possible in Java, you need to find a different solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in java to suffix an object with a `String` to access to a field of it.

Either use reflection to access the fields from the field names or refactor the class so that it provides an implementation key-value with a `Map<String,String>` for example.

Here is a full example with key-value map.

As `ob1` and `ob2` are inner classes, these have some limitations about `static` use (for fields as methods).
So a workaround is declaring the `static` maps and the `static` retrieval method  in the outer class.
It hurts a little the separation of responsibilities but with these modifier constraints, it is hard to do in a different way but using instance fields and methods in the inner classes.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public class ob1 {
      public static final String test = "T1T1";
      public static final String test2 = "T7T7";
    }

    public class ob2 {
      public static final String test = "T2T2";
      public static final String test2 = "T8T8";
    }

    static Map<String, String> valuesObj1;
    static Map<String, String> valuesObj2;

    static {
      valuesObj1 = new HashMap<>();
      valuesObj1.put("test", ob1.test );
      valuesObj1.put("test2", ob1.test2);

      valuesObj2 = new HashMap<>();
      valuesObj2.put("test", ob2.test);
      valuesObj2.put("test2",ob2.test2);
    }

    public static String getVal(int type, String key) {
      return type == 1 ? valuesObj1.get(key) : valuesObj2.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Test.getVal(1, "test"));
      System.out.println(Test.getVal(2, "test2"));
    }
}
```

It prints :

> T1T1
>
> T8T8

Comment: Can you provide a simple example as in question.

Comment: Of course. You are using inner classes. Are you sure to use them in your target ? It would make the example more complex. I said it as you refer to public class in the title of the question.

Comment: Yes... We should use in target

Comment: @davidxxx the uploaded code is using the hard coded values in the hashmap it looks like it is redundant code.

Comment: @Hasnain Ali Bohra Totally right. Thanks a lot. I edited :) Don't hesitate to  directly edit the next time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection to get the values:

```
public static String getVal(int type, String key) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Test$ob" + type);
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(key);
    return (String) field.get(null);
}
```

But in general, it is better to maintain a map for your types with inner maps for the key-value-pairs:

```
Map<String, String> ob1Mapping = new HashMap<>();
ob1Mapping.put("test", "T1T1");
ob1Mapping.put("test2", "");

Map<String, String> ob2Mapping = new HashMap<>();
ob2Mapping.put("test", "T2T2");
ob2Mapping.put("test2", "T8T8");

Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> typeMapping = new HashMap();
typeMapping.put(1, ob1Mapping);
typeMapping.put(2, ob1Mapping);
```

Now your method becomes as easy as:

```
public static String getVal(int type, String key) {
    return typeMapping.get(type).get(key);
}
```

Note, that I intentionally left out failure handling such as unknown types.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getVal(int type, String key) {
    return type == 1 ? ob1.key : ob2.key;
}
```

This attempts to access a static variable named `key` in the class `ob1` and a another static variable also named `key` in the class `ob2`. Neither class has such a variable and the name is completely unrelated to the parameter named `key`. This just will not compile no matter how hard you try.

In Java, variable names are only available at compile time (mostly). This means that you cannot use the value of a `String` variable as a variable name.

Granted there is the Reflection API, but if you find yourself thinking you should use this, you are most likely using the wrong solution for the problem. Reflection is intended for tools, such as IDEs and debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with reflection:

```
public class Test {

    public class ob1 {

        public static final String test = "T1T1";
        public static final String test2 = "T7T7";
    }

    public class ob2 {

        public static final String test = "T2T2";
        public static final String test2 = "T8T8";
    }

    public static String getVal(int type, String key) throws Exception {
        return getVal(type == 1 ? ob1.class : ob2.class, key);
    }

    private static String getVal(Class<?> type, String key) throws Exception {
        if (key != null) {
            Field field = type.getDeclaredField(key);
            if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && field.getType() == String.class) {
                return (String) field.get(null);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong argument: "+key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Test.getVal(1, "test"));
        System.out.println(Test.getVal(1, "test2"));
        System.out.println(Test.getVal(2, "test"));
        System.out.println(Test.getVal(2, "test2"));
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
T1T1
T7T7
T2T2
T8T8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to get to the static Strings. However, instead of using static inner classes, if you have access to class Test, you could refactor it to use a Map.

Answer (score 0):

a solution without reflection and maybe not that clean, but working fine for this example

```
public static String getVal(int type, String key) {
    if (type == 1) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
            return ob1.test;
        } else {
            return ob1.test2;
        }
    }
    if (type == 2) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
            return ob2.test;
        } else {
            return ob2.test2;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not scalable at all.

Comment: Of course it is, but using it on objects with, dunno, 50 members, would be too tedious. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Please find my solution code :-

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public class ob1 {
        public static final String test = "T1T1";
        public static final String test2 = "T7T7";
        public ob1() {
              valuesObj1 = new HashMap<>();
              valuesObj1.put("test", ob1.test );
              valuesObj1.put("test2", ob1.test2);


        }
    }

    public class ob2 {
        public static final String test = "T2T2";
        public static final String test2 = "T8T8";
        public ob2() {
              valuesObj2 = new HashMap<>();
              valuesObj2.put("test", test);
              valuesObj2.put("test2",test2);
        }
    }

    static Map<String, String> valuesObj1;
    static Map<String, String> valuesObj2;

    public static String getVal(int type, String key) {
        return type == 1 ? valuesObj1.get(key) : valuesObj2.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t =new Test();
         t.new ob1();
         t.new ob2();

        System.out.println(getVal(1, "test"));
    }
}
```